# How to get NSObject value into String in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My separate NSObject class file call LocationDetails.swift

```
class LocationDetails: NSObject {

    var name:String!
    var place_Id:String!  

}
```

UIView Controller where i assigning values to object, i have all the values stored in NSDictionary call arrayLocations and i want to get specific details from it to my object using didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
import UIKit

import CoreLocation



var objLoc:LocationDetails = LocationDetails.new() 

class CategoryMainView:  UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

 override func viewDidLoad() {

}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    getLocationsObject(self.arrayLocations[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)
    println("location object: \(objLoc)")
    println("\(objLoc.name)")
    println("\(objLoc.place_Id)") //Here im getting correct output all the time

}

func getLocationsObject(sender: NSDictionary){
    objLoc.name = sender.valueForKey("name") as! String
    objLoc.place_Id = sender.valueForKey("place_id") as! String
}

}
```

In my next ViewController where i want to show all those details in object

```
import UIKit

class RatingView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var ShopName :UILabel!



override func viewDidLoad() {

self.ShopName.text = objLoc.name

}



}
```

But this always give me nil values. Why it gives me nil values any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object values already are strings, so you can access them by calling

```
objLoc.name
objLoc.place_Id
```

You can set them to labels as easily:

```
myLabel.text = objLoc.name
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Btw i want to access the value from another ViewController but it gives me nil value

Comment: Can you give us more details ? How is the object passed between the view controllers ?

Comment: My object class file name is LocationDetails.swift, So In my next UIViewControllers (which i use to show all the detail), i just did the same i create var objLoc like this,

 var objLoc:LocationDetails = LocationDetails.new()

And simply try to get details like objLoc.name, but always it gives nil values

Comment: If those values are nil it means you never set them. If you create two objLoc objects, the values won't automatically pass from one to the other

Comment: Yes Tom is right, either you can create a constructor to set default values or you should set values for the object. Unless you don't do any of these your object properties will be nil

Comment: So what i have to do is declare it globally and use same  objLoc object in both UIViewControllers ryt?

Comment: Yes that is a possibility

Comment: Still it gives me nil. I'm accessing same objLoc object now

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us your code ? With code from both classes, it is not possible for us to help you if not

Comment: When is your RatingView created ? It needs to be loaded after the didSelectRow.

Comment: Wooow it was the bug! I just drag the Cell and created the Modal seague to RatingView earlier. So RatingView loaded before the didSelectRow. That was the bug so i created custome seague with identifier and gave it in didSelectRow. Now it works fine. Thanx alot @TheTom that was a big help.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly set the value as your object has the String values :

```
label.text = objLoc.name
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Btw i want to access the value from another ViewController but it gives me nil value

Comment: In which class are you creating the object

Comment: I create a seperate NSObject class file in my project call LocationDetails.swift and call it in my UIViewController,

var objLoc:LocationDetails = LocationDetails.new()